# Connecting to Microsoft Office 365 on Android programmatically

Tags: android, exchange-server, msdn, exchangewebservices

How to connect to **`Microsoft Office 365 on Android`** programmatically.
Please provide some samples to show **`how to integrate Office 365 in android`** .

Comment: @hai bison : i need some guidance , that's why i posted this question . plus I'm a beginner in android. I goggled this topic, but didn't get much help..

Comment: I'm sorry I could not help. The question is very general.